# How to may multiple lines pattern with regular expression

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, multiline

I want to match SYSTEM definition from my code. System block definition is as below:

```
  "customized system name" = SYSTEM              
  TYPE             = PSZ   
  Other system definition
  FAN-SCHEDULE     = "S1 Sys1 (PSZ) Fan Sch"
   CONTROL-ZONE     = "EL1 South Perim Zn (G.S1)"
  ..
```

My code sample is listed below:

```
 $---- First SYSTEM block
 "EL1 Sys1 (PSZ) (G.C5)" = SYSTEM          
   TYPE             = PSZ    
  FAN-SCHEDULE     = "S1 Sys1 (PSZ) Fan Sch"
   CONTROL-ZONE     = "EL1 South Perim Zn (G.S1)"
   ..    

 $---- First ZONE block
"EL1 West Perim Pl Zn (G.W9)" = ZONE                
   TYPE             = CONDITIONED    
   ..    

 $---- Second SYSTEM block
"EL1 Sys1 (PSZ) (G.W4)" = SYSTEM              
   TYPE             = PSZ    
  FAN-SCHEDULE     = "S1 Sys1 (PSZ) Fan Sch"
   CONTROL-ZONE     = "EL1 South Perim Zn (G.S1)"
   ..    

 $---- Second ZONE block
"EL1 Core Pl Zn (G.C10)" = ZONE                
   TYPE             = CONDITIONED    
   ..
```

With my limited knowledge, following Regular expression is created to match only the system block:

```
^"(.*?)= SYSTEM(.*?)\.\.
```

But after matching the first system block correctly, the expression will mistakenly match the second Zone and system block together:
[Mis-match screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EfX2.jpg)

I am wondering how to improve my expression.

Comment: Is the "may" in the title meant to be "match" or "make" or something else?  Please fix it.

Comment: You've not identified the context (language) in which you're going to use the regular expressions.  Languages such as Awk, Perl, Python, Java, JavaScript, C#, … all have different views on issues such as how to match past line endings.  You should identify which language you plan to use.

Comment: It is eQUEST, an energy simulation definition file.  I use notepad++ regular expression find function as shown in the screenshot.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with this regex:

```
^".*? = SYSTEM(?:(?!\s*\.\.)[\s\S])+
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/XGm3H7/1)

**Explanation**: We make use of a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html) to assert the two dots the end of the `SYSTEM` block. And `[\s\S]` as a modified `.` to match everything across multiple lines.

Regarding Notepad++: Ensure to switch off the option `. matches newline` and it will work.

Comment: Great, we are almost there and how to include the last two dots in the match?

Comment: I add    (.*\s*)(\.\.[\s\S])    to the end of your expression to match the last two dots and it works:

    ^.* = SYSTEM(?:(?!\s*\.\.)[\s\S])+(.*\s*)(\.\.[\s\S])

Thanks!!!